# Order and Chaos and Codegolf

Tags: code-golf, board-game

[Order and Chaos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_and_Chaos) is a variant of Tic-Tac-Toe played on a 6x6 board. What makes the game unique, however, is that both players can place either an X or an O! Each turn (starting with Order), a player places an X or O in any unoccupied square.
Winning is simple. Order wins if there are 5 Xs or Os (vertically, horizontally, or diagonally) in a row on the board. Chaos wins if the board is filled and there are no strings of 5 Xs or Os on the board. Your job? Well, since this is **Programming** Puzzles and Code Golf, you're going to program the game, and golf it.

#### The Rules

- You must accept input as `x y t`, where `x` and `y` are coordinates, and `t` is the tile type (`X` or `O`). Coordinates start with `0 0` in the upper-left corner and increase up to `5 5` (the lower-right corner).
- You must accept `q` to quit, and print `INVALID` if the user enters invalid coordinates, tiles, any input not in the form of `x y t`, or tries to place a tile where there already is one. (The only exception is `q`, as this quits the program.)
- If Order wins, you will output `P1 WINS`. If Chaos wins, you will output `P2 WINS`.
- Order must go first.
- A blank space is represented by `.`.
- Tiles are `X` and `O` (uppercase). You do not have to accept lowercase, but uppercase is required.
- Your board must only consist of `.XO`.
- You're actually simulating both players playing the game, not being given a board and checking who wins. It accepts a move as input, then prints the board, accepts another move, and so on, until one player wins.

The starting board looks like this:

```
......
...... 
......
......
......
......
```

And after the first player (Order) inputs `1 2 X`, it should look like this:

```
......
...... 
.X....
......
......
......
```

Likewise, when the next player (Chaos) inputs `3 3 O`, it will look like this:

```
......
...... 
.X....
...O..
......
......
```

And this continues until one player wins.

As always, [Standard loopholes which take the fun out of everything](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/38891) are forbidden.

The winner is the one with the shortest code on June 15, 00:00 UTC (about one month from when this challenge was posted.)

Comment: What if a player types in a position that is already taken?

Comment: @Loovjo It returns `INVALID`. I've edited that in now, thanks.

Comment: Should the game exit once 5 tiles are in a row are detected?

Comment: Maybe I overlooked it but does it have to print the board to the screen or just check the state of the board and output which player wins?

Comment: @Andrew I actually meant to simulate the game. You accept each player's input, one turn at a time, and then check if a player has won each turn. Is the description unclear?

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes. Once 5 tiles are in a row, it quits and prints `ORDER WINS`.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI `ORDER WINS` or `P1 WINS`?

Comment: @xebtl Sorry, messed that up. It prints `P1 WINS` if there are 5 tiles in a row, and `P2 WINS` if the board is full with no chains of 5 tiles in a row.

Comment: Yes the description is unclear. The board have to be printed at each turn or not?

Comment: @edc65 Yes, it does. I'll make sure it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PHP, 316

Here is my submission. It has to be executed by php in the command line.

Note that this code produces notices because of some shortcuts I made. Let me know if this is ok. I can fix it by adding a few more characters. I checked [this page](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/php-and-warnings) and the top answer says to assume that error reporting is turned off if there is no mention about it.

```
<?for(;$i++<6;)$b.='......|';while(($a=trim(fgets(STDIN)))!='q'){preg_match('/^([0-5]) ([0-5]) ([XO])$/',$a,$d)&($b[$c=$d[2]*7+$d[1]]=='.')?$b[$c]=$d[3]:print"INVALID\n";echo str_replace("|","\n",$b); foreach([0,5,6,7]as$e)preg_match('/(X|O)(.{'.$e.'}\1){4}/',$b)-1?:die("P1 Wins");strstr($b,'.')?'':die("P2 Wins");}
```

And here is the un-golfed version of the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

for(;$i++<6;)$b.='......|';
while(($a=trim(fgets(STDIN)))!='q'){

    #Validate and assign 
    preg_match('/^([0-5]) ([0-5]) ([XO])$/',$a,$d)&($b[$c=$d[2]*7+$d[1]]=='.')?$b[$c]=$d[3]:print"INVALID\n";
    
    #Output
    echo str_replace("|","\n",$b); 
    
    #Check if Order wins
    foreach([0,5,6,7]as$e) {
        preg_match('/(X|O)(.{'.$e.'}\1){4}/',$b)-1?:die("P1 Wins");
    }
    
    #Check if Chaos wins
    strstr($b,'.')?'':die("P2 Wins");
}
```

Comment: Yes, notices are OK.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 360

**Edit** Modified interactive game, should run even in MSIE

As requested, text based game, input via popup, output in console (so to have a monospaced font).

Quit game with 'q' or clicking 'cancel' at prompt.

Not using ES5 features, it should run on any moder browser (where you can have a JS console panel)

```js
b='\n......'.repeat(6).split('');
for(h=t=0;!h&t<36;)
{
  i=prompt();
  if(i=='q')i=null;
  i=i.match(/([0-5]) ([0-5]) ([XO])/);
  m='INVALID';
  if(b[p=i?i[2]*7-~i[1]:0]=='.')
  {
    ++t;
    b[p]=i[3];
    m=b.join('');
    for(x=z='',c=0;c++<6;)
      for(x+='_',z+='_',r=0;r<6;r++)
        x+=b[c+r*7],z+=b[c<4?c-1+r*8:c+1+r*6];
    h=(/X{5}|O{5}/.test(b.join('')+x+z))
  }
  console.log(m);
}
console.log("P"+(2-h)+" WINS")
```

**Now, some more fun** Interactive and graphic version, run snippet to play.

```js
function start() {
  b=Array(7).join('\n......').split('');
  t=0;
  $('#O').text('');
  $('table')[0].className='';
  show();
  $('th').eq(1).html('Left-click: O<br>Right-click: X');
  $('#B')
  .off('mouseup')
  .on('mouseup','td.F',function(ev){
    var x,y, p=~~this.id.slice(1)
    x=p%7-1
    y=p/7|0
    b[p]=ev.which > 1 ?'X':'O';
    ++t
    for(x=z='',c=0;c++<6;)
      for(x+='_',z+='_',r=0;r<6;r++)
        x+=b[c+r*7],z+=b[c<4?c-1+r*8:c+1+r*6];
    show()
    if (/X{5}|O{5}/.test(b.join('')+x+z))
      end(1)
    else if(t==6*6) 
      end(2)
    return false
  })
}

function end(w) {
  var n=['Order','Chaos'][w-1]
  $('th').eq(0).text('P'+w+' '+n+' Wins')
  $('th').eq(1).text('Click to play again')
  
  $('table')[0].className=$('tr')[0].className =n[0];
  $('#B').off('mouseup').on('mouseup', start)
}
function show() {
  var w,p
  p=t&1
  $('tr')[0].className=$('#B')[0].className='OC'[p];
  w=b.map(function(c,i){
    return c>' '?'<td class='+(c=='.'?'F':'X')+' id=C'+i+'>'+c+'</td>':'</tr><tr>'
  }).join('');
  $('th').eq(0).text('Playing: '+['Order','Chaos'][p]);
  $('#B').html('<tr>' + w +'</tr>');
}

start()
```

```css
th { 
  font-size: 12px;
}
.C th { color: #807; }
.O th { color: #047; }
.C td.F:hover { background: #f0e; }
.O td.F:hover { background: #0fe; }
table.C td { background: #f0e; }
table.O td { background: #0fe; }

td {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th colspan=6></th></tr>
  <tbody id=B></tbody>
  <tr><th colspan=6></th></tr>
</table>
<p id=O></p>
```

Comment: Nice clickable version!  (Minor suggestion: you could use right/left click instead of the radio buttons.)

Comment: @xebtl I'll give it a try

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 453

```matlab
format plus 'XO.'
disp(F=zeros(6))
r=@()fread(0,1);R=@()r()-47;q=@(m)printf(m)&&quit;e=@()q("INVALID");l=@(n)n<1||n>6&&e();s=@()r()==32||e();w="P1 WINS";f=@(v)abs(sum(v))==22.5&&q(w);g=@(m)any(abs(sum(m))==22.5)&&q(w);d=@diag;while 1
i=R();i==66&&quit;l(i);s();l(j=R());s();F(j,i)&&e();abs(v=R()-36.5)==4.5||e();F(j,i)=v;disp(F)
r();f(d(F,-1));f(d(F,0)(2:6));f(d(F,0)(1:5));f(d(F,1));g(F(1:5,:));g(F(2:6,:));g(F(:,1:5)');g(F(:,2:6)');F&&q("P2 WINS");end
```

The implementation is quite straightforward, the only real “trick” to use `format plus` to take care of printing.
Here is a commented version:

```matlab
format plus 'XO.'               # this is where the magic happens

## initialize and print empty board
disp(F=zeros(6))

## shortcuts
r=@()fread(0,1);
R=@()r()-47;
q=@(m)printf(m)&&quit;
e=@()q("INVALID");
l=@(n)n<1||n>6&&e();
s=@()r()==32||e();
w="P1 WINS";
f=@(v)abs(sum(v))==22.5&&q(w);
g=@(m)any(abs(sum(m))==22.5)&&q(w);
d=@diag;

while 1
  i=R();                        # read index 1
  i==66&&quit;                  # ‘q’?
  l(i);                         # check bounds
  s();                          # read and check space
  l(j=R());                     # read and check index 2
  s();                          # read and check space
  F(j,i)&&e();                  # square already filled?
  abs(v=R()-36.5)==4.5||e();    # valid mark?
  F(j,i)=v;                     # assign …
  disp(F)                       # and print board
  r();                          # read off newline

  ## check diagonals
  f(d(F,-1));
  f(d(F,0)(2:6));
  f(d(F,0)(1:5));
  f(d(F,1));

  ## check rows
  g(F(1:5,:));
  g(F(2:6,:));

  ## check columns
  g(F(:,1:5)');
  g(F(:,2:6)');

  ## check chaos
  F&&q("P2 WINS");
end
```

Because of the requirement to check input syntax and validity, the code uses `fread()` to read one character at a time.

I took care to output the board and messages in a tidy manner.  If some extra output is acceptable, I could shave off a couple of bytes.  For example, using automatic printing (no `disp(F)`), the board would be shown as

```matlab
F =

......
......
......
......
......
......
```

Also, I interpreted that each move is given on a separate line.

---

Sample interaction (the `-q` switch is just to suppress Octave's header):

```matlab
$ octave -q order_chaos.m 
......
......
......
......
......
......
3 3 X
......
......
......
...X..
......
......
2 3 O
......
......
......
..OX..
......
......
3 3 O
INVALID
```

The invalid move caused the program to exit (not sure if that was intended).

Comment: Just to make sure (because there was some confusion earlier), this takes input from both players, and actually simulates the game, rather than just checking if a given board wins?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Just so. It expects each move of the form `x y t` on a separate line (and no other input).

Comment: And it prints the board after every input?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Yes, see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 565 chars D:

```java
public class M{public static void main(String[]r){int[]p=new int[36];int u=0;for(;;){String l=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();if(l == "q")break;int a=l.charAt(0)-'0'+(l.charAt(2)-'0')*6,i=p[a]==0?1:0;if(i>0)p[a]=l.charAt(4);u+=i;r(i==0?"INVALID\n":"");if(u==36){r("P2 WINS");break;}for(int x=0;x<6;x++)for(int y=0;y<6;y++)for(int d=0;d<3;d++)try{int e=1,c=p[x+y*6],z=x,h=y;if(c=='X'||c=='Y'){for(;e<6;e++){if(d%2==0)z++;if(d>0)h++;if(p[z+h*6]!=c)break;}if(e==5){r("P1 WINS");return;}}}catch(Exception e){}}}static void r(Object o){System.out.print(o);}}
```

This is probably the longest code-golf ever. I'm really not good at this.